# Change calendar month with button

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a calendar in PHP. I have it displaying the current month, but I would like to add submit buttons to go to the next or previous months. Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
  /* calendar */
  table.calendar        { border-left:1px solid #999; }
  tr.calendar-row   {  }
  td.calendar-day   { min-height:80px; font-size:11px; position:relative; } * html div.calendar-day { height:80px; }
  td.calendar-day:hover { background:#eceff5; }
  td.calendar-day-np    { background:#eee; min-height:80px; } * html div.calendar-day-np { height:80px; }
  td.calendar-day-head { background:#ccc; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:120px; padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #999; border-top:1px solid #999; border-right:1px solid #999; }
  div.day-number        { background:#999; padding:5px; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; float:right; margin:-5px -5px 0 0; width:20px; text-align:center; }
  /* shared */
  td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np { width:120px; padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #999; border-right:1px solid #999; }
</style>
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
  /* draws a calendar */
  function draw_calendar($month,$year){
/* draw table */
$calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

/* table headings */
$headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
$calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

/* days and weeks vars now ... */
$running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
$days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
$days_in_this_week = 1;
$day_counter = 0;
$dates_array = array();

/* row for week one */
$calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

/* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
    $days_in_this_week++;
endfor;

/* keep going with days.... */
for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
        /* add in the day number */
        $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

        /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
        $calendar.= str_repeat('<p> </p>',2);

    $calendar.= '</td>';
    if($running_day == 6):
        $calendar.= '</tr>';
        if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
            $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
        endif;
        $running_day = -1;
        $days_in_this_week = 0;
    endif;
    $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
endfor;

/* finish the rest of the days in the week */
if($days_in_this_week < 8):
    for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    /* final row */
    $calendar.= '</tr>';

    /* end the table */
    $calendar.= '</table>';

    /* all done, return result */
    return $calendar;
}
$currentmonth = date('m');
//echo "$currentmonth - ";
$currentyear = date('Y');
//echo "$currentyear";
$months = array('January','Feburary','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
$years = array('2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020');
echo "<h2>${months[$currentmonth-1]} ${years[4]} </h2>";
echo draw_calendar($currentmonth,$currentyear);
/* sample usages */
/*
echo '<h2>March 2014</h2>';
echo draw_calendar(3,2014);

echo '<h2>April 2014</h2>';
echo draw_calendar(4,2014);
*/
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Based on some searching, it looks like a way to do to this would be to use sessions, something like what I have below, however I'm not exactly sure how this works or how I would go about implementing it. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if($_POST['submit']){
     $_SESSION['i'] = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? ++$_SESSION['i'] : 0;
    echo $_SESSION['i'];
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that stores both the current month and year as `SESSION` variables, and can increment and decrement smoothly through months and years. E.G. if you get to December 2014, the next button takes you to January, 2015.

This code begins right after your function `draw_calendar` ends. This should get you started. Note that I'm not really using your months and years arrays. I do use it once for the title above the calendar. But I didn't use the years array. You can incorporate that later if you like. I also added a `Today` button to reset the values to the current month and year.

```
session_start(); //don't forget this...
$currentmonth = date('m');
$currentyear = date('Y');

$months = array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
$years = array('2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020');

//sets initial value of SESSION variables to current month and year
if(!isset($_SESSION['month'])){
    $_SESSION['month'] = $currentmonth;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['year'])){
    $_SESSION['year'] = $currentyear;
}

//increments or decrements year based on user input
if(isset($_POST['LastMonth'])){
    if($_SESSION['month']-1 == 0){ 
        --$_SESSION['year'];
    }
    $_SESSION['month'] = ($_SESSION['month']-1 > 0) ? --$_SESSION['month'] : 12;

}

if(isset($_POST['NextMonth'])){
    if ($_SESSION['month']+1 == 13){
        ++$_SESSION['year'];
    }
    $_SESSION['month'] = ($_SESSION['month']+1 < 13) ? ++$_SESSION['month'] : 1;
}

if(isset($_POST['Today'])){
    $_SESSION['year'] = $currentyear;
    $_SESSION['month'] = $currentmonth;
}

//print calendar based on SESSION variables
echo '<h2>'. $months[$_SESSION['month']-1] .' '. $_SESSION['year'].'</h2>';
echo draw_calendar($_SESSION['month'],$_SESSION['year']);


//buttons to move around
echo '<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="LastMonth" value="<< Last Month" />
    <input type="submit" name="NextMonth" value="Next Month >>" />
    <input type="submit" name="Today" value="Today" />
    </form>
';

//print_r($_SESSION); //uncomment to keep tabs on your variables
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this will definitely help.